# Wordpress and simple forums

Tags: forum

This might be an annoying question, since there are [some pretty good answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1132/forum-software-that-integrates-with-a-wordpress-blog-website) to this question, but they are 9 months old, so please but bare with me. I would like to have some input to point me to the right direction.

I'm looking to integrate a simple forum for a Wordpress project. The forum must haves:

- Simple threads, similar to the WP
  threaded comments system.
- Ability to display only the forum
  login page as forum front page.
- Ability to show only the forum the
  user is registered to, or the forum
  the admin assigns the user to. In a
  way the flow is:
  Click on forums page > Login > Browse only one specific forum.
- Ability to show some info about each
  of the users: phone, email, etc.
- Ability to register without going to wp-admin

  What I need is way less then what vBulletin or phpBB or even SimplePress provide, i just need a place for users to chat on specific topics and get in touch. I've tried to use bbPress, as it is as close as it gets to what I wanted, but they don't have the ability to close forums for specific groups of users, so maybe one can point me to the right software of combination of plugins.
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: BuddyPress, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you beta-tested the bbPress Plugin? It *should* meet most of these needs.

Comment: Yes I have, but there isn't an option to show specific forum for specific user groups. There are some plugins out there like "Hidden Forums", but those haven't been updated for three years. I might be wrong, though...

Comment: It might not do that *out of the box*, but since it's a WordPress Plugin, it is certainly *capable* of implementing something like that. I'm not sure, but **BuddyPress** might be helpful for per-user-group forum management, as well.